# ¿Cómo hacer una aplicación en c# que saque un inventario del hardware y software?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un problema me pidieron un programa en C# que sacara un inventario de hardware y software de una máquina, y esa información mandarla a una base de datos de SQL server.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Guillermo. Por favor brinda información sobre lo que has hecho o sobre lo que necesitas averiguar. Considera que nosotros no haremos tu trabajo, solo te ayudaremos a resolver dudas/problemas que tengas mientras realizas la solución.

Comment: Que tipo de informacion necesitas exactamente? Entiendo que por hardware necesitas CPU, RAM, etc. Pero por software?

Comment: Deberás especificar que tipos de datos te han pedido obtener para que te podmaos redirigir.

Comment: Desde mi particular punto de vista me parece reinventar el hilo negro, ya que en el mercado existen muchas aplicaciones muy completas que recolectan este tipo de información y existen tanto gratuitas como de pago

Answer (score 3):

Podrias usar las librerias de `WMI` para obtener la info del sistema

[how to get system information remotely using c#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/260729-how-to-get-system-information-remotely-using-c%23/)

es mas hasta podrias obtener esta info de forma remota, ya que con WMI definiendo los datos de acceso a otra pc en la red podrias recuperar los datos de esta.

Para persistirlo en Sql Server deberias conocer `ado.net` usando las clases `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` podrias crear un `INSERT` de sql para volcar los datos en la tabla que diseñes.

Comment: quien voto negativo podria explicar porque? acaso no usaria WMI para obtener los datos de la pc, o deberia completarlo con algun ejemplo

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. Únicamente mediante WMI...

Comment: Por favor, quien vote negativamente, podria dar mas detalles de su voto, asi, ayuda mas a la comunidad

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar la libreria ManagementObjectSearcher que hace parte del namespace System.Management.

Aquí unos enlaces:

[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avtarsohi/2015/05/09/get-computer-hardware-information-using-c/)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avtarsohi/2015/05/09/get-computer-hardware-information-using-c/

Con respecto a la conexión con la base de datos de SQL Server, como lo indica Leandro Tuttini, es necesario que tengas conocimientos en el manejo de Ado.net, sin embargo aquí te dejo un código básico:

```
using(SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection("colocar la cadena de conexión"))
    {
      string sql = "INSERT into tabla (field1,field2,field3,...,fieldN) VALUES (@data1,@data2,@data3,..,@dataN)";

      using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql))
       {
         comm.Connection=conn;
         comm.Parameters.Add("@data1",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value= "data value";

         .....
         comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
         conn.Open();    
         conn.Close();
       }
     }
```

Espero te sirva!